# Adjusting image intensity values

Tags: matlab, pixel, adjustment

I came to the [imadjust](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/imadjust.html) function in `MATLAB`. It seems that this function enhances the contrast of the image. But, what is the theoretical basis for this function? In other words, if I say that this function as mentioned in the documentation adjusts the image intensity values, what does this exactly mean? What is it doing to the intensity values?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you read the following related article: [Adjusting Image Contrast Using the Adjust Contrast Tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/adjusting-image-contrast-using-the-adjust-contrast-tool.html) and play around with [this tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcontrast.html).

Comment: I suggest you try `edit imadjust`

Answer (score 2):

The formula for each pixel is likely to be

```
J = ((((I - low_in) / (high_in - low_in)) ^ gamma) * (high_out - low_out)) + low_out
```

If you leave off all the parameters, `low_in` and `high_in` are automatically selected so that the output contains 1% of its pixels at the highest and lowest values.