# Heat and intensity map in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an issue: there are a 2-D array of intensity - Z [(x,y) is a matrix, and the value is an intensity].

```
1 2 3 4 ...
1 3 4 6 ... // ~ 1000 colums. 
2 6 7 8 ...
```

Creating a heat map: `I=imagesc(Z).`

Then, I want to colorize columns, e.g 100-200 colums - blue color, 200-300 - green, 300-400 - red. Something, like gradient by the columns.

[image]

Many thanks!

UPD*: I have this, and I want to colorize it. by "color filter", e.g Axis X [0,100] -> blue. X [100, 200] - red.

to obtain the image I've attached above. is it possible?

[image]

Comment: your intensity is between 0 and 100? meaning 0 is black?

Comment: yes, 100 - white, 0 is black.  gray colormap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure about colour intensity/light intensity part, but I think this should do the job:

```
intense = [0 2 3 4;1 3 4 6;2 6 7 8];
intense = intense./100; %//Convert to percentage
RGBmat = zeros([size(intense), 3]); %//Create blank RGB map
%//set Col1 to red
RGBmat (:,1,1) = 255;
%//set Col2 to green
RGBmat(:,2,2) = 255;
%//set Col3 to Blue
RGBmat(:,3,3) = 255;

%//multiply intensity
Res = RGBmat .* repmat(intense,[1,1,3]); %//I am not sure about adjusting the intensity of each pixel.
```

According to this post [Adjusting image intensity values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490304/adjusting-image-intensity-values)

it should perhaps look something like this?

```
J = (RGBmat ./ 255).^ repmat(intense,[1,1,3])*255 %//This is assuming that intensity matrix is from 0 to 255 not 1 to 100, you will have to normalize it I guess.

imshow(Res,'InitialMagnification','fit')
imshow(J,'InitialMagnification','fit')
```

Note how 100 intensity is not white,but the default black, this is because when I set RGBmat to default value, I used zeros (which means black), if you want to it to be white, you will need to set RGBmat to zeros(...).*255; HOWEVER, this means when you set the columns to red,green and blue, you will need to set the other channels to zero:

So for red, instead of setting red to 255; you need to set blue and green to 0 instead.

========EDIT FOR UPDATED CONTENT============

Assume your intensity matrix (or your greyscale image) is I

you should first convert it to percentages:

```
Ipercent = double(I)./255;
```

next make it into a 3D RGB image -

```
IRGB = repmat(Ipercent,[1,1,3]);
```

now you can multiply your colour masking into it:

```
%This line will multiply your first 1:100 column with a red mask
IRGB(:,1:100,1) = uint8(IRGB(:,1:100,1).*255);
```

The rest is just adjusting the colours of each section.

Comment: Please, look at my upd.

Comment: @delkov Added solution to your problem

Comment: thanks, how can I plot it? what command? (can it be smoother, not like pixels, if it possible).

Comment: @delkov pixels are because of the size of your intensity matrix, I cannot make it smoother, if you want it not pixelated, you will need a higher resolution intensity matrix. To plot, just use `imshow(IRGB, 'InitialMagnification','fit')` and use `imwrite` when you want to save it as a JPG. The resolution is the same as the size of your Intensity mat, if it is 1080*720 then your image resolution is 1080pix * 720pix.

Comment: I see you.
I've created gray graphs by using `imagesc`, and they are smooth.
I thought, we can write something after to obtain also a "heat map".